# JS Return HTML Title as H1 Headline

Tags: javascript, css

first of all: I‘m not a coder!

I want to inject a dynamic h1 based on page title on a webpage.

Example: `<title>Garden</title>`

Now I need this as H1 class -  I want to include this H1 after a given div class `<div class="teaser"></div>`

It is may totally simple and I already read some stuff but i don‘t get it…

Answer (score 2):

Fairly trivial

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
  h1.innerHTML = document.title;
  document.querySelector(".teaser").insertAdjacentElement("afterend", h1)
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Garden</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="teaser">Teaser</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey thank you! It works, but now i want to include this created h1 after a given div class <div class=„teaser“ how can i place it?

Comment: See update.. I added an eventListener to make sure the DOM is available when adding

Comment: Ok I‘ve tested it localy and all works, but for my live test it won‘t. Maybe I have to say the injection starts after site load - can this be the problem? (I try to inject the code via an AB Testing tool)

Comment: So add my code at the end of the injection (without the load event listener)